# bash: Variable including wildcards not interpreted in grep

Tags: bash, grep, special-characters, wildcard

Within bash, I'm trying to using grep to search input string in multiple files. As I have different patterns matching I use a variable which is filename with wildcards.

I found it didn't interpret the wildcards because it interpreted just as question mark.

```
pattern="Report????.log"
grep -ciF $input "$pattern"
```

If I just write

```
grep -ciF $input Report????.log
```

this definitely works.

So is there a way to solve this if I still want to use variable with wildcards?

Comment: What do you have stored in `input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes in `$pattern` and it will work.

```
pattern="Report????.log"
grep -ciF $input $pattern
```

Comment: However, he *should* quote `$input`.

Comment: Oh quoting probs again... Thank you my life saver!